# Why I cannot see emoticons when I click on my Radiobuttons?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Hello I am working on a project using React and Tailwind CSS and I would like to use Radiobuttons with emoticons but it does not work. Here is my code :

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import "./styles/tailwind-pre-build.css";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ul class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-x-5 m-10 max-w-md mx-auto">
        <li class="relative" />
        <input
          class="sr-only peer"
          type="radio"
          value="yes"
          name="answer"
          id="answer_yes"
        />
        <label
          class="flex p-5 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-lg cursor-pointer focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-50 peer-checked:ring-green-500 peer-checked:ring-2 peer-checked:border-transparent"
          for="answer_yes"
        >
          Yes
        </label>

        <div class="absolute hidden w-5 h-5 peer-checked:block top-5 right-3">
          <span role="img" aria-label="donut">
            
          </span>
        </div>

        <li class="relative">
          <input
            class="sr-only peer"
            type="radio"
            value="no"
            name="answer"
            id="answer_no"
          />
          <label
            class="flex p-5 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-lg cursor-pointer focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-50 peer-checked:ring-red-500 peer-checked:ring-2 peer-checked:border-transparent"
            for="answer_no"
          >
            No
          </label>

          <div class="absolute hidden w-5 h-5 peer-checked:block top-5 right-3">
            <span role="img" aria-label="donut">
              
            </span>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="relative">
          <input
            class="sr-only peer"
            type="radio"
            value="maybe"
            name="answer"
            id="answer_maybe"
          />
          <label
            class="flex p-5 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-lg cursor-pointer focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-50 peer-checked:ring-yellow-500 peer-checked:ring-2 peer-checked:border-transparent"
            for="answer_maybe"
          >
            Maybe
          </label>

          <div class="absolute hidden w-5 h-5 peer-checked:block top-5 right-3">
            <span role="img" aria-label="donut">
              
            </span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I don't know why but I think the attribute `absolute hidden w-5 h-5 peer-checked:block top-5 right-3` doesn't work.

Here is the full project : https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-8kj6l0?file=/src/App.js:0-2276

Could you help me please ? Thank you very much !

Comment: Which effect exactly are you trying to achieve? To display the emoji left of the `yes/no` ? Should the emoji be used as the radio button? what should happen when the radio button is checked?

Comment: You are not importing the right tailwind file. The file you are importing misses a lot of the classes you are using. I would reccomend to follow the official tailwind installation docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/